# Creating new unique rows from a list of possible column values

Tags: python, pandas

Lets assume I have a Pandas Dataframe like this:

```
   C1    C2    C3
0  1     B     v
1  5     D     i
2  1     B     iii
3  3     C     iv
```

Where all possible values of C1, C2, C3 are

```
C1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
C2 = ['A','B','C','D','E']
C3 = ['i','ii','iii','iv','v']
```

The ask is to print new rows to exhaust all possible combinations of C1, C2, C3 that are not already in the existing dataframe.

Is there a better way than to have 3 nested loops ranging all the values of C1, C2, C3 and comparing each combination to the existing list?

Comment: What is the structure of this array? Is it a pandas dataframe? I guess, making your array a set of lists and compare it with `itertools.product(*allCs)` would be faster than three nested loops.

Comment: Um, what do you mean by "array"? Do you actually mean `pandas.DataFrame`?

Comment: Yes, sorry, data frame. I'll update the answer

Comment: and what is the expected output?

Comment: I did not get you question... Do you have dataframe or list ??? What data structure are you using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this,

```
C1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
C2 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
C3 = ['i', 'ii', 'iii', 'iv', 'v']
existing = ((1, 'B', 'v'), (5, 'D', 'i'), (1, 'B', 'iii'), (3, 'C', 'iv'))

import itertools
result = [i for i in itertools.product(C1, C2, C3) if i not in existing]
```

Comment: Make `existing` a set, to speed up the lookup time.

Answer (score 0):

```
series_1 = pd.Series(C1)
new_data_frame['C1'] = series_1.values
series_2 = pd.Series(C2)
new_data_frame['C2'] = series_2.values
series_3 = pd.Series(C3)
new_data_frame['C3'] = series_3.values
for index, row in new_data_frame.iterrows():
    if existing_dataframe[existing_dataframe == row].shape[0] == 0:
         existing_dataframe.appen(row)
```